# Counting Zero-Sum Paths in a Tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

We are given a tree with `N (up to 100,000)` nodes. Each edge is weighted either `+1` or `-1` and nodes are numbered from `1` to `N`. How many unordered pairs `(A, B)` exist such that on the path `A -> X -> B`, where `X` (`X != A && X != B`) is some vertex on the path between `A` and `B`, the sum of edge weights on the path `A -> X` is `0` and the sum of the edge weights on the path `X -> B` is `0`?

It follows that we only care about even path lengths, or else the sum of the edge weights cannot be `0`. We cannot iterate on potential `A` and `B`, or else we get an `O(N^2)` solution, which will not run under 1 second. Any tips on how to solve it? The program should run under 1 second, so an `O(N)` or `O(N logN)` solution would work.

Edit: However, if we can calculate the number of good paths starting from each node, we would be able to solve the problem. Is it possible to calculate this? Sounds DP-ish to me, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you know anything about the tree topology?  Is it binary?  Balanced?

Comment: It can be any type of tree as it isn't specified.

Comment: Moderator should move it to cs.stackexchange or programmers.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to develop an algorithm below that starts off as `O(N^2)`. With a small observation we can change the complexity to something substantially smaller. I'm not quite sure what it will be  (`O(N)` or `O(NlnN)`), but it seems to be less than `O(N^2)`.

1. In the tree, choose an arbitrary leaf node `x0`, and create an empty list `L0`.
2. Follow the leaf node up one branch. If the list is non-empty add the value of this edge weight to each term of the list, this records the cumulative sum of the edge weights so far.
3. Append this edge weight to the list.
4. If this new node only has 2 branches, goto step 2 by traveling up the only new direction and updating `L0`. Repeat until there are 3 or more branches on the new node.
5. For each branch (other than the direction we came from) recursively start on each sub-tree with step 1, except in this sub-tree mark this node as special. When the recursion reachs back to this node it will merge (step 5) and halt.
6. Merging: We now have a set of lists `L0, L1, L2, ...` that must be merged into `L0`. Each of these lists represent the different paths and their respective cumulative sums. For each pair in each list, add to the counter, `m` the number of times these sums are equal to zero. **This associates a sum for each possible path in the graph**. Create a new list `L0` that is a concatenation of the set `L0, L1, L2, ...`.

The algorithm above works, but since we are performing a sum for each graph path, the cost must be at least `O(N^2)`.

The trick here is to *not count every path*. If instead, we sort the lists, determining if two sorted lists of size `k1,k2` have a fixed sum `c` can be done by simply iterating through the lists, one forward one backwards. So the counting can be done for each pair of lists in `k1+k2` operations not `k1*k2` operations as before. Merging the lists is also trivial and has the same complexity since they are already sorted.

**Bonus:** The above method trivially extends for arbitrary edge weights (not just `-1, 1`) and an arbitrary fixed sum (not just zero).

Comment: Can you expand on step 5? I'm not sure how this can be combined together, since the path could start/end from somewhere in the middle of the chain.

Comment: @Bartlomiej You're absolutely right that I was missing the sub-paths. You are supposed to add these in when you come across the node for the first time. I've updated the answer and hopefully addressed your point in steps 2-4.

Comment: How can you find the zero sum paths when merging multiple (WLOG 2) paths without iterating through all of them?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this will be useful, but if anything, I think you could use this property:
Take a pair `(A,B)` for which such a path exists. We then know that the sum of the edge weights (which I will call the distance of the end vertices) of the path `A -> ... -> B := d(A,B) = 0`, because

`d(A,B) = d(A,X) + d(X,B) = 0 + 0 = 0`

As you remarked, we only care about paths of even length; this suggests that when actually checking the pairs, we first color the tree in two colors (since all trees are bipartite) which can be done greedily in Θ(n), and only consider pairs of vertices within each color group. Of course this doesn't improve the complexity of the number of pairs we will have to consider since we still have (n/2)*(n-1)/2 vertices in each color, and the term is in Θ(n^2) where `n` is the number of vertices.

Now as you said, you can count the paths in Θ(n^2) using BFS and checking all pairs of vertices in each color group. Here is another thought that might help you:

Say we have two vertices V and U for which `d(A,V) = d(A,U)`. We have two cases:

1. `A -> ... -> V = A -> ... -> U -> ... -> V`, meaning U (WLOG) lies on the unique path from A to V. Then we have

   `d(A,V) = d(A,U) + d(U,V) <=> d(A,V) = d(A,V) + d(U,V) <=> d(U,V) = 0`

   So if U and V lie on the same path and have equal distance to A, the distance `d(U,V) = 0`.
2. The two paths fork somewhere; let the vertex where the paths fork be K. We then have

   `d(A,V) = d(A,K) + d(K,V) <=> d(K,V) = d(A,V) - d(A,K)` and

   `d(A,U) = d(A,K) + d(K,U) <=> d(K,U) = d(A,U) - d(A,K)` and

   `d(U,V) = d(K,U) + d(K,V) = d(A,U) + d(A,V) - 2*d(A,K) = 2*(d(A,U) - d(A,K)) = 2 * d(K,U)`

   So if `U` and `V` don't lie on the same path, their distance to each other depends on the distance either vertex has to `A` and the distance `A` has to `K`; or, simplified, just on the distance of either vertex to `K`. More generally, the fact that `d(A,U) = d(A,V)` only implies `d(U,V) = 0` in the case that either vertex lies on the path from `A` to the other one, so you can't really tell anything by equal distances if the latter condition isn't the case.

Whether any of this will help you, I don't know. I couldn't figure out how to achieve what you ask for in subquadratic time, and I assume it's not possible; to me, the problem feels distantly related to all pairs shortest paths, which has time complexity in O(n^2) using BFS for each vertex as a start vertex. That is more a fuzzy feeling than anything even dimly resembling a convincing argument though.

Comment: I've been thinking about this for while; especially the approaches of iterating on `X`, the arbitrary intermediate vertex, or `A`, one of the starting vertices. If we can count this quickly we have an `O(N)` solution, but easier said than done.

Comment: I'm curious, do you have any ideas on how iterating on only one of the three vertices involved (A,B,X) can cover all possible pairs?

Comment: You could do a DFS from each start node, remember when you hit a zero, that would be the `X` node, then just continue the DFS until you hit zero again.

Comment: But wouldn't that only give you the number of such paths for a given start vertex? Considering you then would have to iterate over the n possible different start vertices, that would still end up giving you a complexity of n * complexity(DFS) = O(n^2), which is what I assumed you suggested to do in the OP.

Comment: Yeah I never claimed to have a `O(N)` algorithm, although I'm trying to work toward one. I have a feeling it might be dynamic programming since we're trying to count a value, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: If we end up needing to calculate arbitrary `d(U,V)` we can root the tree and use LCA to calculate those too.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought maybe you had thought of something I didn't realize. I'm not really good at figuring out dynamic programming solutions, but maybe papers about DP solutions regarding all pairs shortest path can be inspiring since they're bound to deal with the problem of having O(n^2) pairs of end vertices of the paths.  In particular, I would try having a look at [this paper](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~demetres/docs/dapsp-full.pdf), but I can't promise you that it'll help. I couldn't find anything on DP for trees, the fastest APSP for trees really seems to be n times BFS/DFS.

Comment: Yeah you could do that, and for trees with inner vertices that have high degrees (so the tree is flat) that may give you a performance boost on average - if you figure out how to use that property for (U,V) that don't lie on a common path from the source.

Comment: Yeah but I can't guarantee the topology of the tree. It could be a string of nodes, for example, and that would be bad for some algorithms.